# Plot Numpy results in the browser with a JavaScript chart library using Server-Sent Events

Tags: javascript, numpy, matplotlib, flask, server-sent-events

I'm building an application in Numpy but I'm not quite satisfied with matplotlib (altough a great library). I would prefer using a javascript plotting library in the browser (e.g. http://www.chartjs.org/)

I'm already quite familiar with Flask and the browser technologies. I can use server-side events to populate the data on the client side. I'm thinking of having one chart in the browser and update this chart when I want to plot something by updating the data

The only difficulty I am facing is that I want to be able to send these server-side events from the console (so **not from my application**)

Is this possible? Should I run the app in a different process and send a server-side event from another process (being the console)? How can this be done?

Comment: You should look at the webagg backend that is currently on the master branch.

Comment: Have a look at Vegalive (Vega build on top of D3.js):
http://sampsyo.github.io/vegalive/

I definitely hope this area will see some action in the coming years. Be it the new mpl webagg, bokeh perhaps (?) or something else...